# How to combine two JSON objects together

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have two JavaScript obj like so:

```
const objOne = {
  "firstname": "xzxz",
  "lastname": "xzxzxzx"
};

const objTwo  = {
  "title": [
    {
      "name": "foo",
      "table": "First"
    },
    {
      "name": "bar",
      "table": "Second"
    }
  ]
};
```

and I want to combine them like below (not sure if "combine" is the appropriate word but hopefully make sense)

```
{
  "firstname": "xzxz",
  "lastname": "xzxzxzx",
  "title": [
    {
      "name": "foo",
      "table": "First"
    },
    {
      "name": "bar",
      "table": "Second"
    }
  ]
}
```

so far I tried the below

```
   let result = [];
     results.push(objOne);
     results.push(objTwo);
```

but surely the result is not the one I want and it make sense as I create an array and I push into both objects.

```
[
  {
    "firstname": "xzxz",
    "lastname": "xzxzxzx"
  },
  {
    "title": [
      {
        "name": "foo",
        "table": "First"
      },
      {
        "name": "bar",
        "table": "Second"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Just a nitpick, but you don't have JSON.  You have objects.  JSON is a _string representation_ of data that _resembles_ object syntax.

Comment: @ Rocket Hazmat I agree, two obj which I wanted to be serialized like so, my brain was fried when i was writing this question...Spent few hours on this, it seems that this question was even answered already. I should have used "merge" when I was googling this but being a java boy...for me a merge is merge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
const objOne = {
  "firstname": "xzxz",
  "lastname": "xzxzxzx"
};

const objTwo  = {
  "title": [
    {
      "name": "foo",
      "table": "First"
    },
    {
      "name": "bar",
      "table": "Second"
    }
  ]
};

const output = { ...objOne, ...objTwo };
console.log(output);
```

Comment: well, I was nearly there, spent few hours on this stuff...tried all, except this. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Object.entries()` to convert the objects into arrays and `Object.fromEntries` to convert it back into an object.

```js
const objOne = {
  "firstname": "xzxz",
  "lastname": "xzxzxzx"
};

const objTwo  = {
  "title": [
    {
      "name": "foo",
      "table": "First"
    },
    {
      "name": "bar",
      "table": "Second"
    }
  ]
};

const combined = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(objOne)
  .concat(Object.entries(objTwo))
);

console.log(combined);
```